# How to open recordsource of another MS Access through MS Access addon

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created an MS Access addon, which opens a form, this form has buttons that open other forms that are in the addon:

[image: Image of Form]

The problem is that this addon is trying to get the record source from the addon and these tables do not exist in the addon and they should not. It should open or fill the record source from the MS Access file.

I already tried to call query and on open of the form typed

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Galaxy_dokument;"
```

hoping that this would bypass it and find the table because if you call `DoCmd.OpenTable` it works...

## UPDATE

Got it...

add **"On_Load"** event to a form and type in:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT * FROM YourTableName IN '" & CurrentProject.Path & "\" & CurrentProject.Name & "'"

Me.RecordSource = SQL
```

Just to understand the static code would look like these:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Galaxy_dokument IN 'C:\WorkingDirectory\Your_AccessFile.accdb';"
```

Comment: Why don't you set table links to other file?

Comment: I do not understand how OpenTable could work if table is neither local nor linked.

Comment: Well my thoughts were the same…, you know access does some weird stuff all the time , it probably search for a table in addon first (where the code was used in) and if it can’t find it then it probably starts the  search in other database I assume…

Comment: You have a form in addon that should use data from working db? Not sure library db is intended to work that way. I've never used one. Access does not do 'weird stuff all the time' in my experience. It does what it is told to do.

Comment: @june7 Exactly, i am trying to use data from working db..., well thanks anyway, I'll just keep looking for solution, when I'll have some time to spare in meantime i hope someone pups up with a solution :)

Comment: Instead of editing your question with solution, write an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...

add **"On_Load"** event to a form and type in:

```
Dim SQL As String

SQL = "SELECT * FROM YourTableName IN '" & CurrentProject.Path & "\" & CurrentProject.Name & "'"

Me.RecordSource = SQL
```

Just to understand the static code would look like these:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Galaxy_dokument IN 'C:\WorkingDirectory\Your_AccessFile.accdb';"
```

Comment: You can also use CurrentProject.FullName I think